# Tizen Samsung Smart TV - please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I'm building a Samsung Smart TV web application using Tizen Studio, my application run perfectly on Samsung TV simulator but when I try to deploy my app on real Samsung Smart TV, I got this error: "Tizen Samsung Smart tv - please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences".

I've tried to find solutions for this problem on internet, even on Samsung developer website but Tizen OS has a very small community and poor documentation so I'm currently stuck trying to deploy my app to real Samsung Smart TV.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much information, so I can only guess. If deployment to a Smart TV is done in a similar fashion as with Signage Displays and if you are attempting to deploy to a device *from* the IDE, then usually a setting is required to allow a connection between the display and your IDE.

For SAMSUNG signage displays there is an option, called "Developer Mode". It can be reached from the HOME menu and is **mandatory** if you want to connect your IDE to a device. There may be an analogy for Smart TVs.

This is however only for when you attempt to deploy your application to a real device from the IDE. If however you deploy like you would in a real-world-scenario, so not from the IDE, then this is not where the problem lies. A typical cause of problems are certificate settings, so make sure to check those.